# ALM REST API to Get Linked Defects

Tags: rest, api, hp-alm

I want to get Defects Linked to Test Case, given the Test Case ID using REST API.
ALM Version, which I am using: 11.52

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume the right URL. Please let me know if it works:

```
https://alm/qcbin/rest/domains/[domain]/projects/[project]/defects/?query={test-reference[1782]}
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. But this is not available yet in 12.01. Here is error I get: The field [test-reference] of [defect] doesn't support filtering